# Injecting Fake Data with Unity DI

Tags: mocking, unity-container, repository-pattern

I would like to be able to **serve a faked/mocked data from a repository while the code is in development**. That is, when debugging or on the some CI machine the mocked data gets served up.

This way I can let the UI guys have a "working" service to start implementing their UI. Or the testers can start testing earlier.

I know I could just hard code the data into the service. But then that code is in the service and will probably be deleted when the service is ready (or worse, stays in there). I'm thinking I could reuse these mocked data for e.g unit tests or just to make the code clearer.

So my question: **Is this something that is supported in Unity and/or is there a best practice for this? Or is this just insane idea?** :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common scenario that lot of developers come across.

1. You using DI. So one of the most important thing is that you should be able to configure your container to resolve a Fake implementation until the real service is ready. As you have mentioned UI dev can continue, and testers can start testing early.
2. When the real implementation comes in you don't want to have the fake data being served to the UI any more. Therefore configure your container to resolve the real implementation. Do not remove the Fake implementation as you may never know you might need it in future. This includes temporary service unavailability so the development can continue with the fake implementation serving data.
3. This is the most important part. I would not recommend that you mix your Fake data with Unit Tests. Keep your tests completely isolated and *only* serve the test fake data (absolutely necessary) resides within the Unit Test project. Assuming if you decided to re-use the Production Fakes in test your test may likely to fail for a wrong reason. For example, invalid data setup. This can also be maintenance issue. For example someone might decide to remove the fake data as the real services are stable. Now if the tests have dependency to those files there will be issues. You want to keep your test data independent from other fake data.

   ```
   public interface IWebService
   {
       string GetData();
   }

   public class RealWebService : IWebService
   {
       public string GetData()
       {
           //please don't use. More work happening
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }

   //avoid using this for the testing. It is only a replacement until the new service in place.
   public class FakeWebService : IWebService
   {
       public string GetData()
       {
           return "faleData";
       }
   }

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var container = new UnityContainer();

           //TODO: Un comment this when the RealWebService implementation is ready to consume.
           //container.RegisterType<IWebService, RealWebService>()

           //TODO: Remove this once the RealWebService implementation is ready to consume.
           container.RegisterType<IWebService, FakeWebService>();

           //return the fake implementation so...
           // As you have mentioned UI dev can continue, and testers can start testing early.
           var webService = container.Resolve<IWebService>();
           webService.GetData();
       }
    }
   ```

Comment: Ok I agree with your points. Good to have that validated. But how would you technically implement the "toggle"?

Comment: @Sturla I have updated my answer with some code and comments.

Comment: You can implement the "toggle" using preprocessor directives (#if) if you configure Unity in code OR configure unity in app.config that allows you to change inyections by hand without recompile and/or use several app.config for develop, test, production enviroment.